# Multiple resources with the same id

Tags: android-layout

Although I cannot find a specific reference I assume that you cannot give the same id to resources in two different activities. eg. `myTextView` in Activity 1 and `myTextView` (with nothing to link them) in Activity 2. If this is so, how is a `ListView` in a ListActivity, which has to be called "list", handled when you have two or more ListActivities?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I would like to tell you is, you can give id's in the XML files not in Activities. However we access those elements in activities via their ids.

*You can have same id for two or more elements in **different XML files***

*But you cannot give same id to two or more elements in **same XML file***

In your activity find out a line in the `onCreate` method,

`setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_XML_FILE);`

So whenever you will access any element with an id, it will search only in the above mentioned XML file, not in any other.

So as you will be having different XML files in different activities, so each activity will look for resource in its own XML file. It will have no effect on any other resource in any other XML file.